# Bot didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I write bot for the telegram with `telebot` and `Django` . And when i running him on the server and watch the full log, I have next text:

```
Internal Server Error: /bot/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fishbot/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fishbot/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view bot.views.bot didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Somebody help me?

P.S i can not attach `telebot` on the tags 0:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you must return `HttpRequest` instances in your views.

Try doing something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def current_datetime(request):
    response = '' # Put whatever you want to return in here.
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Thx! This was helping me